# How to disable SMTP auth plain for Citadel 8.20 on Slackware 14.0?

Tags: email, slackware, smtp, slackbuilds

How do I turn off SMTP AUTH PLAIN for Citadel 8.20 on Slackware 14.0?
If I set up postfix to handle SMTP would this allow me to not have SMTP auth plain enabled